# listening help (British accent) - what does it smell like?

Tags: listening

[**Youtube link**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVdg9vbFoso&t=70s)
[**link audio only**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GGIRl7tDabJKwjQPxF3O03rrRlkC1ZM9/view?usp=drive_link)

as a non-native, if I listen to the Youtube link, it sounds like...
"OK, what **is** it smell like?"

but, the script is...
"OK, what **does** it smell like?"

in my case...
"**does**" sounds like "**is**" to me.

**[Question]**
What would it be if you **transcribed this sentence as you hear it?**

The meaning of this sentence or grammar is not important to me.
My focus is on listening.

thx for reading this humble post.

Comment: The speaker is clearly saying "What does it smell like".  The word "does" is unstressed.  This is normal in fast connected speech. . . . it sounds like "Wha'dz it smell like". Sometimes people will go further and fully contract the word, from "what does it smell like" to "what's it smell like". Sometimes, depending on the speaker/situation/accent it can sound like "wotsit smell like".   There's also a brand of cheesy maize snacks in the UK called ["Wotsits"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wotsits).

Comment: I (American) don't hear a syllable between *what* and *it*!  But to elide the *t* of *what* here, or to assimilate it to the *d*, would not be uncommon in rapid casual speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*What does it*" can be contracted to "*what's it*".

It's common in some British dialects, and in casual speech, for "*what's it*" to come out sounding like "*wazzit*". That's what you're hearing.

I note that the subtitles are simultaneously displayed in both Korean and English, which is an indicator that they are not likely to be a transcript of what was spoken, because it would have to translate directly, so colloquialisms and contractions may well have been taken out deliberately.